# Mysql select rows with same id's (3 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following tables:

'blog_content'

[image: blog_content]

'blog_media'

[image: blog_media]

'blog_media_content'

```
| blog_id | media_id   |
========================
|  1      |      1     |         
|  2      |      2     |  
|  3      |      3     |       
|  3      |      4     |
```

I want to select all `blog_media.uri`'s where `blog_media.media_id` equals `blog_media_content.blog_id`.

Please help me to achieve my aim.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` among the three tables would give whatever info you want.

Comment: SELECT uri FROM blog_media WHERE media_id IN (SELECT media_id FROM blog_media_content WHERE blog_id = 3)      any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `inner join` between `blog_media` and `blog_media_content` tables would suffice.

```
SELECT 
bm.uri 
FROM blog_media bm 
INNER JOIN blog_media_content bmc ON bm.media_id = bmc.media_id
WHERE bmc.blog_id =3;
```

**Note:**

If you need any additional information from `blog` table then you need an additional `inner join` like below:

`...INNER JOIN blog_table b ON bmc.blog_id = b.blog_id...`

**EDIT:**

In order to get records for all `blog_id`s :

```
SELECT 
bm.uri 
FROM blog_media bm 
INNER JOIN blog_media_content bmc ON bm.media_id = bmc.media_id
ORDER BY bmc.blog_id;
```

Comment: can i do that ?: SELECT 
bm.uri 
FROM blog_media bm 
INNER JOIN blog_media_content bmc ON bm.media_id = bmc.media_id
WHERE bmc.blog_id = bm.media_id;  ?

Comment: Syntyax wise this is correct.But what's the use of such query? I mean do you want records of only those where blog_id and media_id are same?

Comment: Please check the query that I've given first. Let me know how good this one works for you.

Comment: it works fine but it only gives me the images for blog_id 3 :/ i want images for all blog_id's

Comment: Then just remove the `where clause`

Comment: what do you want actually?

Comment: i'm using 1 foreach loop to display the content of one post and one loop for the images.

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the above sample data?

Comment: i think my foreach loops need to know what images he has to display otherwise he displays them all, but how can i get the blog_id from the first loop. i'm using smarty btw